# BlockUI plugin: how to call it manually?

Tags: blockui, jquery-blockui

I am using JQuery BlockUI plugin for my project. Here is the link of this tool:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

I am hoping to call it manually before heavy (non-Ajax) computation and end it after it. I tried many times, but not able to get it work. I tested the following:

```
$.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#00f' } });
```

before doing the heavy computation. But no blocking.

### Update 1

I already have

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI(bui)).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

in my program and it is work perfectly.

Now I want to use `$.blockUI` for non-ajax call only in this place, but it is not working.

### Update 2

Here is code structure. I tested BlockUI in two places separately, but not working.

```
$.blockUI(); //place 1

$.ajax({
      url: '/js/a_big_map_file.js',
      dataType: "script",
      async: false,
      success: function(mapjs) {

      $.blockUI(); //place 2
      ...
      //heavy computation is here
      ...
});
```

Comment: **[Works good for me](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h7eaykg0/1/)**.. What's not happening..? Did you check for any console errors?

Comment: I dont see anything in Chrome's console by using "inspect".

Comment: Just try running `$.blockUI()` in `console`..

Comment: $.blockUI() works just fine in console. I updated my post with more info.

Comment: Can you share the exact code, like when exactly you are trying to do this? Without that its very difficult to help up with...

Comment: Updated the post to show the code.

Comment: That's `ajax` part right? Its working fine as you said. Which `non-ajax` part you were talking. You said _heavy (non-Ajax) computation_. Post code for that please.

Comment: I updated my post. The part inside "ajax-success" takes a while to finish and show content. During this process, I dont see any BlockUI blocking working.

Comment: Call `$.blockUI();` again inside `success`. Did you?

Comment: Called $.blockUI() at the beginning inside the "success" block. No effect. Thanks for helping me!